# Select or highlight data on map by click on legend

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to select or highlight data on a leaflet map in by clicking on the legend in Rshiny?
example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(leafletGeocoderRshiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  p(),
  actionButton("recalc", "New points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rexp(100, 2), z = runif(100))
  pal = colorBin('PuOr', df$z, bins = c(0, .1, .4, .9, 1))

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({ leaflet(df) %>%
    addCircleMarkers(~x, ~y, color = ~pal(z)) %>%
    addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~z)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have not seen anything to achieve this yet. Would be interesting to know.

Comment: Package [**leaflet.extras**](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras) has functionality to link legends and data via highlighting. See this demo https://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/geojsonv2, specifically examples 2.1, 2.2 and 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent updates (0.2) to the `mapedit` package may help: http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/06/09/mapedit_0-2-0.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: Offtopic: What do you use to create the gif? :)

Comment: @BigDataScientist gifs are from the linked site.

Answer (score 2):

I got close, but ran out of time now. But i decided to share anyway, maybe someone else sees a solution to the last step.

So far it works for the first click on any of the rectangles in the legend. It doesnt work for any following clicks as the map is redrawn and with it the onclick listeners are deleted. I didnt find a way to add them again so far,...

Its a hacky aprroach: I add onclick listener to the boxes and decided to update the colors via R as i didnt see a good way in JS.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(leafletGeocoderRshiny)
library(shinyjs)

colors <- c("#000000", "#222222", "#888888", "#FFFFFF")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  leafletOutput("map"),
  p(),
  actionButton("recalc", "New points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  global <- reactiveValues(colors = colors,
                           bins = c(0, .1, .4, .9, 1))

  observe({
    print(input$interval)
    isolate({
      if(!is.null(input$interval)){
        lowerBound <- as.numeric(unlist(input$interval))
        global$colors <- colors
        global$colors[which(global$bins == lowerBound)] <- "#FF0000"
      }
    })
  })

  session$onFlushed(function() {
    runjs("
      var legendButton = document.getElementsByTagName('i')
      var elem; var interval;
      for (nr = 0; nr < legendButton.length; nr++) {
        elem = legendButton[nr]
        elem.onclick = function(e){
            console.log(e.target)
            interval = e.target.nextSibling.nodeValue.split(' ');
            Shiny.onInputChange('interval', interval[1]);
        }
      } 
    ")
  })


  df = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rexp(100, 2), z = runif(100))
  pal = reactive({
    colorBin(global$colors, df$z, bins = global$bins)
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({ leaflet(df) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(~x, ~y, color = ~pal()(z)) %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal(), values = ~z)
  })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = T)
```